# how to use debtags in conjuction with when a package arrived in the debian repository?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

Is there a way to use debtags and search within a specific time-frame ?

For instance/example, let's say I want to know which game packages came in since 2016 till date.

Now AFAIK the debtag for game would be "use::gameplaying" and while it gives enough results (the archive/package index already updated) there doesn't seem to be a way to narrow down using debtags alone. The debtags documentation on the wiki doesn't get me anywhere. Neither did the enhanced debtags search service. https://debtags.debian.org/search/

Look forward to seeing something.

Comment: What do you mean by "came in"? Do you mean the year they were first added to the official Debian repositories?

Comment: yup, the year when they were first added to the official debian repo, on the spot.